# What's the best way to set up unit testing in dart with the new test library?

Tags: unit-testing, dart, dart-pub, dart-html

There are a lot of resources out there for unit testing in dart using the old `unittest` library, but I can't find much about the `test` library, which was just released at the end of last year.

In `unittest` you could call `useHtmlConfiguration()` or `useHtmlEnhancedConfiguration()` that would serve up test results on `localhost:8081` or whatever port you used with `pub serve`. The new library doesn't seem to have that, or at least it's not well documented. So my first question is: Is there a good way to run unit tests in the browser by typing `localhost:8081` like with the old library, or does everything have to be done from the terminal?

I'm able to run the tests with `pub run test:test --pub-serve=8081 -p firefox`, but I'm just wondering if anyone has some "best practices" with this library to share since it's so new.

Answer (score 2):

The test package only prints progress and test results to the console. WebStorm/IntelliJ in the most recent version provide a GUI API for running the tests.

The readme https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/test is quite comprehensive about how to use the package.

I wouldn't say the new `test` package is so new anymore. I'm using it since more than a year AFAIR and almost all packages maintained by the Dart team and probably most others are already migrated to the new `test` package.

Comment: Where is the WebStorm GUI? Not that a GUI is a big deal, I just haven't seen it since I started looking. Part of my problems have been OS-specific: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35666136/how-do-i-install-dartium-on-ubuntu