# How do I install dartium on ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, dart, dartium

I was able to install chromium by using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`, and I was able to install the dart sdk by manually downloading it and sticking it in a bin. However, I haven't been able to find how to install dartium, which has stuff that doesn't come with either chromium or dart sdk (ex: content_shell and other support for the dart test library). I'm using a 32 bit Lubuntu distro. Thanks for the help!

Comment: See if [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/663523/getting-and-installing-dartium) helps. Ask such questions on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Comment: Thanks for the advice -- I'm new to linux, so I wasn't aware of that resource; though @JonusBojesen 's answer was just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer the manual install, very easy and you can switch between versions, they are just located in different dirs.

Download from here, either the dev or stable, what you prefer. As said above, you can have both just located in different dirs.
https://www.dartlang.org/downloads/archive/

Then unzipped the package in the prefered location. You end with this, where chrome is the executable.

```
devel$ ls dartium-lucid64-full-stable-1.14.2.0/
chrome                  icudtl.dat        nacl_helper            resources
chrome.1                lib               nacl_helper_bootstrap  resources.pak
chrome_100_percent.pak  libffmpegsumo.so  nacl_irt_x86_64.nexe   xdg-mime
chrome-wrapper          libpdf.so         pnacl                  xdg-settings
extensions              locales           product_logo_48.png
```

After this, two things are to concern.
a) In my environment, Dartium has consistently over several clean Ubuntu installations been missing `libudev.so.0` So if you experience problems, start it for the command line, where this should be presented. In my case the solution is just to make a symbolic link.

```
 ls -la /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 feb.  24 23:42 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 -> libudev.so.1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 feb.  24 20:59 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 -> libudev.so.1.6.4
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 122624 okt.  15 14:02 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1.6.4
```

If you like confirmation of this, it is described here
https://askubuntu.com/questions/663523/getting-and-installing-dartium

b) If you run Chrome/Chromium beside, then to avoid dragging your personal settings into Dartium runs, use the `–user-data-dir` flag, this is described more here:
https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartium/

Comment: For a better solution than the symlink for `libidev.so.0` see https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/12325#issuecomment-192638769 (`LD_PRELOAD=/home/mulander/.steam/ubuntu12_32/steam-runtime/amd64/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0 ./chrome`)